# Build tokens are not resolving for VSTS Gradle build task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In order to have unique version codes for android build, we are passing the version code as a parameter in gradle build task. Parameter value is in the following format: $(Year:yy)$(DayOfYear)$(rev:r).

Build command from the logs:

[command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "D:\a\3\s\gradlew.bat "-PversionCode=$(Year:yy)$(DayOfYear)$(rev:r)" build"

The build tokens are not resolved.Error details as below:

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
For input string: "$(Year:yy)$(DayOfYear)$(rev:r)"

Comment: Hi Santosh,
Please provide screenshots with the Gradle task inputs in your build definition and detailed debug log of a build. (Set the system.debug variable to true for the debug log.)
Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These variables aren’t the built-in build variables, but can be used as build number format.

Regarding your environment, you can add/update the variables through [Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md).

For example:

1. Set build number format to `$(Year:yy)$(DayOfYear).$(rev:r)` or other (just want to retrieve the value of rev:r)
2. Add PowerShell task to add a variable (`PversionCode`)

script:

```
$date = get-date
$year=$date.year
$dayOfYear=$date.DayofYear
write-Host $(Build.BuildNumber)
$r="$(Build.BuildNumber)".split(".")[-1]
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PversionCode;]$year$dayOfYear$r"
```

3. Using in Gradle task (Options: `-PversionCode=$(PversionCode)`)

Comment: Thank you, adding variables via Logging command resolved the issue.